# BeautifulSoup doesn't shows all the elements in tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse [this website](http://www.autobody.ru/catalog/10230/217881/) and get information about auto in content-box `card__body` with `BeautifulSoup.find` but it doesn't find all classes. I also tried `webdriver.PhantomJS()`, but it also showed nothing.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.autobody.ru/catalog/10230/217881/'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib') 
JTitems = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"content-box__strong red-text card__price"})
JTitems
```

or

```
w = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"content-box card__body"})
w
```

Why doesn't this approach work? What should I do to get all the information about auto? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: are you sure those elements are in the page, with these specific classes  ?

Comment: Include some of the markup in the question.

Comment: There are no element with class `content-box card__body` in the website, if you could include the exact text you want to extract it would be helpful for everyone trying to help.

Comment: i am trying to extract this text - 2208р (red color ) and everything that's below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `table` where your necessary info are. Then find all the `tr` and loop through them to get the texts.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.autobody.ru/catalog/10230/217881/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

price = soup.find('div', class_='price').get_text()
print(price)

for tr in soup.find('table', class_='tech').find_all('tr'):
    print(tr.get_text())

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks , it's worked and showed all articles great , but it wont showed see red price 2208 р

Comment: @egorkh I've updated my code, it will print price too.

Comment: thanks alot for your help. Its very strange , when i tryed look at html code of price i see -  <p class="content-box__strong red-text card__price">2208 Р</p>, but you used class price , how did you get this class ? how can i find it too ?

Comment: I found it by looking at the page source. I didn't inspect element.

Comment: it seems i am absolute zero in parsing tell me please , how can i look at page source

Comment: Open the page in your browser, right click anywhere on the page except any link and you will see an option "View page source".

Comment: ok, i was using same way when i looked at elements , and class name which i see is - content-box __strong red-text card price. I attach screenshot screenshot-http://pastenow.ru/9085449b06a6022f978c102587fa849a

Comment: @egorkh which browser and device you were using ?

Comment: well, I'm using chrome on windows 7. Don't know actually why is this happening.